# Why is this simple binary search not returning correct value of mid though outputiing correct mid value?

Tags: c++, c++11, search

for `A = {1,2,3,4}` and function call `b_search(3, 0, arr.size() - 1, arr) //arr being a vector`.
 When I print `mid` inside the function it returns 2 but when I return `mid` in place of printing `mid` it returns value 0.

```
int b_search(int tbs, int p, int q, vector<int> A){
    if (p < q) {
      int mid = p + (q - p) / 2;
      if (A[mid] == tbs){
         return mid;
      } else if (tbs < A[mid]) {
         b_search(tbs, 0, mid - 1, A);
      } else {
         b_search(tbs, mid + 1, q, A);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings, and it would warn you about missing return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `return` recursive calls.You are making recursive calls but are not collecting the value returned from those recursive calls.You are assuming that subsequent calls(recursive) will return the answer to main but it is going to return the ans to the point where you are making the recursive call.At that point you should collect the answer and return it to main.

```
else if(tbs<A[mid]){
     return b_search(tbs,p,mid-1,A);//note the return
  }else{
     return b_search(tbs,mid+1,q,A);//note the return
```

Also it should be

```
        b_search(tbs,p,mid-1,A)
```

instead of

```
        b_search(tbs,0,mid-1,A)
```